# OSX high sierra time machine server

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, time-machine

since updating (fresh install!) to OSX high sierra the server app does not offer the time machine settings anymore.

The changelog somehow reflects that, but refers to the system settings --> sharing as a replacement for it.

However, I was unable to find any useful information on how I could use that as a backup option for my network clients again. Anyone can point me to the right way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From release notes :

*Caching Server, Time Machine Server, and File Sharing advanced options are now built directly into macOS.*

Time Server option has moved to the Preferences pane. Right-click on a shared folder in the *Sharing* preferences pane, then select *Advanced options*. This is where to set up Time Machine Server now.

The reason for this weird change is not documented as far as I know.